# sqlldr only loading first character of string into column

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load data into a database table using sqlldr. 
The issue I'm encountering is that only the first character of each line is being loaded.
I am using Oracle version 12.1 on AIX.
My data is a single column text file.
Each record is of variable length.
In this test set we limit the data to 10 characters.
Each row is on a new line.
It should be loaded into a single column table.

My empty table is defined as:

```
create table test_table (test_num varchar2(10));
```

My data looks like but without the doublespacing:

```
3675536758

8370530737

9318078

5395653669
```

Looking at the data in `od -c` it looks like:

```
0000000    3   6   7   5   5   3   6   7   5   8  \n   8   3   7   0   5
0000020    3   0   7   3   7  \n   9   3   1   8   0   7   8  \n   5   3
0000040    9   5   6   5   3   6   6   9  \n
0000051
```

My control file looks like:

```
load data
 infile 'test.txt' "str '\n'"
 into TABLE test_table
 (test_num char "trim(:test_num)")
```

The issue I have is only the the first character each line is being loaded into the table.

This behavior persists with or without the trim function and with or without the `"str '\n'"`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `test_num char(10)` in lieu of `test_num char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, `terminated by whitespace` might help:

```
load data
infile * 
replace
into table test_table
(test_num  terminated by whitespace
)
begindata
3675536758
8370530737
9318078
5395653669
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orclcontrol=test23.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pet Vel 23 07:45:32 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 3
Commit point reached - logical record count 4

SQL> select * from test_table;

TEST_NUM
----------
3675536758
8370530737
9318078
5395653669

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for both of these solutions. I used the white space solution because it does not require me to define the size of the data beforehand which make this method more flexible.

Comment: Be aware that `sqlldr`'s internal buffer for character data is 255 characters.  So, if the column is not explicitly sized in the control file, and the data for that column in the file is greater than 255, that row will fail to load even if the column in the table is large enough for it. Play it safe by always creating the control file with sized character columns then you don't have to worry about it.  To test, make a column varchar2(500) and try to load 256 characters into it.

Answer (score 4):

Modify `(test_num char "trim(:test_num)")` to `(test_num char(10) "trim(:test_num)")` and the records will be loaded as expected.

char would be one character whereas char(10) would be 10 characters.

On a windows server, I changed the control file to not use the stream record format (not the source of the problem).

```
load data
 infile * 
 into TABLE test_table
 (test_num char(10) "trim(:test_num)")
BEGINDATA
3675536758
8370530737
9318078
5395653669
```

[image]

We see these records now:

```
SCOTT@erptst>select * from test_table;
TEST_NUM
3675536758
8370530737
9318078
5395653669
```